# Work problem with only one worker doing multiple tasks

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I don't believe I have enough information to answer this unusual work problem. It was posed as "A worker must complete 3 sequential tasks: Process items from group A at x items/hr,  process items from group B at y items/hr, and process items from group C at z items/hr. How many items can he process in an hour?"

Nothing was stated about whether or not each task must be completed in its entirety before moving onto the next. I can't see a way to make a statement as to what outcome one would get under different algorithmic approaches. I do know, however, that you cannot move faster than your slowest "component." So, if A is 2 items/hr and B is 3 items/hr and C is 3 items/hr, the worker will process 2 items at most. This would mean the answer is $\text{min}\{x, y, z\}.$

Am I missing something here?

Comment: I agree it's poorly worded.  I expect that the idea is that the worker does one $A$, then one $B$, then one $C$, then back to $A$.

Comment: It's not as simple as taking the minimal rate. If rate A is 2 items per hour, at most he can do is maybe one item because he needs time to perform other tasks as well.

Comment: @Vasya -- absolutely. As mentioned above, the wording here is horrid. I can imagine a few variations on how the problem would play out in real time.

Comment: @Ryan: Agree that the wording is poor. What lulu is suggesting makes the most sense though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming he spends equal time on each task, he would process
(x + y + z)/3 items per hour.
Switching tasks between each item would likely be time consuming.
For example each task is at a different location in the wotk area.
Does sequential mean one x item, one y item, one z item or does it mean do the x items, then the y items and finally the z items.  Repeat every hour.

Comment: You're asking the same questions I am, but have the most reasonable response thus far, so you win! I've still got to find time to play around a bit more with it. Many thanks for the reply!